# asp.net mvc membership error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i am getting this error on the asp.net mvc default site when i try to log in:

**An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: connectionString**

this is in the file "AccountMembershipService" on the below code

```
 public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        return _provider.ValidateUser(userName, password);
    }
```

any ideas on what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your connection string in the web.config to work with your current envirement :)

Answer (score 0):

probably your asp.net membership provider couldn't connect to the sqlserver so it can verify your details. try running the asp.net wizard again or something.

Answer (score -1):

actually it was just a typo in my connection string in web.config